# OpenModelica internal time strictly seconds?

Tags: openmodelica

Trying to run a model with rates defined as "per day", while Modelica expects "per second". Changing the model rates is complex and potentially troublesome.

I wonder if Modelica can be set to a different time unit for simulation.

Probably using the wrong vocabulary to search as I can't find much helpful information on this.
It seems that the time unit of seconds is or at least was built in to Modelica.

Did try to convert model to rates "per second". It kind of works, but than flow rates and controllers also need to be set to this time unit. This is totally impractical from an engineering point of view.

Would be easier to change internal time unit.

Can anyone confirm that seconds are compulsory for rates? Or even better: Can anyone point me to changing the defautl "internal" time unit?

Thank you!

Comment: The unit for built-in variable time is seconds, but you can change the display unit. In the end a day is just 86400 seconds.
Please add a minimal working example to your question so other see what you try to do. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

In the plotting view you can change the simulation time unit.

[image: Changing the units]

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your answers. I am aware of the possibility to change display time units. I take it as a confirmation that models in OpenModelica should be set up keeping in mind the internal time unit of seconds. So I'll adapt the modell I'm using. I guess there might also be the way of using the unit attribute for parameters defining process rates and thus describe them properly. Will try out. Maybe.